# get element from string converted to json object in GSON

Tags: java, json, gson

I have a json string that looks as follows

```
{ "shares": [ { "shareId": "5792c70c470ac0c817000002", "type": "group", "rule": "view", "subscribe": false, "everyone": true } ] }
```

It is an array of one object. I would like to get the string "5792c70c470ac0c817000002" from it.

I was able to get the JsonObject as follows

```
String jsonString  = "{ \"shares\": [ { \"shareId\": \"5792c70c470ac0c817000002\", \"type\": \"group\", \"rule\": \"view\", \"subscribe\": false, \"everyone\": true } ] }\"
JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
JsonObject jsonObject = parser.parse(jsonString).getAsJsonObject();
```

However, I would like to get the member shareId of the first member of this array. How can I do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
jsonObject .getJsonArray("shares").getJsonObject(0).getString("shareId");
```